# What is the original creation myth of Hawaiian mythology?

Tags: creation, hawaiian

According to what I read in the Internet, there are two variants of the creation myth in Hawaiian mythology. According to the [first](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C4%81ne) [two](http://ancienthawaiiangods.weebly.com/kane.html) websites, the god Kane emerged from Chaos or *Po* and he creates the world with two other gods who emerge from *Po*, Ku and Lono. According to the [third one](https://glitternight.com/2011/03/02/eleven-more-deities-from-hawaiian-mythology-2/), Kane is a child of the Earth Mother Papa and Sky Father Rangi and he separates them from their embrace so that he and his other siblings can have space to live. Which one of these myths is the original one, or is there another creation myth which is older?

Comment: *According to what I read in the Internet* could you provide links to the websites you read?

Comment: @Hamlet https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C4%81ne and http://ancienthawaiiangods.weebly.com/kane.html is the link for the one where Kane comes from Chaos and https://glitternight.com/2011/03/02/eleven-more-deities-from-hawaiian-mythology-2/ for the second myth. I remember that there were more websites about the second myth but I can't seem to find them at the moment.

Comment: Could you edit this question to include these links? And in the future, it's always a good idea to cite the source of any information you read online.

Comment: @Gibet Isn't Tane the hawaiian version of Kane? Also, I recently found out that Hawaiians called the sky father "Wakea". According to Wikipedia, Wakea is the "son" of some people,meaning that he can't possibly be the original god. Do *you*  know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could read the Kumulipo, Papa and Wākea werenʻt the first beings, but Pō and I think Laʻilaʻi. If you want a simpler shorter version starting with Papa (Earth mother) and Wākea (Sky Father) this is what I learned from my kumu:

[image]

I think Rangi is not part of the Hawaiian version.

Hāloa is the first man who all Hawaiians descended from and this is why the islands, taro and the people are all related and this is why people need to take care of the land, who is family.

Comment: And what about the gods?